# Installing Ubuntu on windows laptop without losing access to windows

Tags: software-installation

I'd like to start using ubuntu as my primary OS on a new Dell XPS 15 9550. It came with windows 10 installed, and I want to be able to go back to that if issues arise with ubuntu. I'm new to both OS's, and would like to know how to avoid losing access to the original software. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just do a standard dual-boot.

To avoid possible MFT errors, resize the Windows 10 partition in Windows first, so that the Ubuntu installer doesn't have to.